# How to make a TCP outgoing connection with Docker container?

Tags: sockets, go, docker, connection

My Go application makes [TLS connections via `tls.Dial()`](https://github.com/andradei/quickfix/blob/feature/ssl/connection.go#L75) to exchange data.

It works fine when run from the host:

[image]

But the outgoing connection doesn't seem to work when the app is run from a Docker container. The app hangs indefinitely.

[image]

**Note 1**: Same behavior with using `docker run -p $(docker-machine ip):2500:2500 ...`

**Note 2**: VM doesn't have extra port forwarding settings other than the default settings that came with docker-machine's default VM.

Docker image build with Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src/path/to/app"
# Install dependencies
RUN go get github.com/path/to/dep

VOLUME "$GOPATH/src/path/to/app"
EXPOSE 2500
WORKDIR "$GOPATH/src/path/to/app"
CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

Host is OS X running *docker-machine*.

### Question

How can I make the TCP outgoing connection to work?

Comment: `What are the requirements to set up a container for TLS connections?` same as a regular-host requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are either using boot2docker or docker-machine (since you are running docker on OSX). If you are using boot2docker, you have to forward the ports on VirtualBox as well as docker, have a look at this blog post:
https://fogstack.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/docker-on-osx-port-forwarding/

If you are using docker-machine, you have to connect to the docker-machine assigned ip, not localhost, have a look at this post:
https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/710

I see now that you are using docker-machine specifically, so the post about docker-machine should answer your question.

Edit: I misunderstood the question. You are trying to make an outgoing connection on a forwarded port. That is not correct. By default docker can make outgoing connections on any port. The port forwarding is for incoming connections only. Please try again without specifying any ports to forward. My suspicion  is that you are trying to make an outgoing connection on the incoming (forwarded) port.

Comment: Your second link was helpful to a point. I got another web app (that is a server) to work. How can I get it to work on an app that is a client (the app I refer to in this question)? In the app in question, I tried `docker run -p $(docker-machine ip):2000:2000 -v $GOPATH/src/path/to/app:/go/src/path/to/app myContainer` without success.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I might be completely wrong on my assumptions. Let me know if it makes a difference or not. If not I'll try to recreate the situation on my end.

Comment: I haven't set up port forwarding. And you are correct, I'm trying to make a TCP outgoing connection.

Comment: I updated the question with more information based on the input from this answer.

Comment: On what port are you attempting the outgoing connection?

Comment: 2500 in reality. I used 2000 as an example. The idea is that I'm using the same port for incoming and outgoing connections.

Comment: Why are you forwarding a port? Outgoing connections do not require any port forwarding. You cannot use the same port for incoming and outgoing connections on the same ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had exactly the same problem. Was unable to connect out at all.

Restarted the container, and suddenly outgoing connections worked fine. It's possible that the container survived an update of docker?

Currently using Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4